# BigDecimal precision explosion

Tags: java, scala, math, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision

I'm trying to do calculations in Scala (and/or Java) at a fixed precision larger than that of a double.  I'm using BigDecimals with Scala's default [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL128), which has precision 34.  Even though all the inputs have this precision, I'm finding that after a few computations, the precision of the results starts to explode.

Here's an example computation that I think illustrates the problem:

```
import math.BigDecimal

val z40 = BigDecimal(0).setScale(40) // 0E-40
z40.scale                            // 40
z40.precision                        // 1
(1 + z40*z40).precision              // 81
```

the result is 81, which is higher precision than `z40`.  In my case, I'm never using setScale, but zeros with very large scales are arising in computations.

This is not the behavior I want. I would like `(1 + z40*z40)` to have precision 34 -- the precision of the MathContext in which the computations are being performed (since `z40*z40` is negligibly small compared to 1).  How can I get this kind of arithmetic?

**Update:** This behavior is due to a [change in the handling of MathContexts](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/3a1332c451) between Scala 2.9.* and 2.10.*.  (Thanks to Paul Phillips for pointing out the commit.)  See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/xibgQ9BCa7I/discussion).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scale` instead of `precision` in your code?

Comment: "When a MathContext object is supplied with a precision setting of 0 (for example, MathContext.UNLIMITED), arithmetic operations are exact, **as are the arithmetic methods which take no MathContext object**." Maybe you need to pass the `MathContext` explicitly?

Comment: @ntalbs yes, you're right -- fixed above.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it looks like [Scala's BigDecimal wrapper](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/math/BigDecimal.scala#L1) does pass in the `MathContext` in, e.g., the `+` method.  Is that what you're recommending? If so, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @davidsd Not knowing Scala, I just made a guess based on the docs for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems strange. I tried your code and get the result as you expected:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_10).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import math.BigDecimal
import math.BigDecimal

scala> val z40 = BigDecimal(0).setScale(40)
z40: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0E-40

scala> z40.scale
res0: Int = 40

scala> z40.precision
res1: Int = 1

scala> (1 + z40*z40).precision
res2: Int = 34

scala> _
```

As you can see, `(1+z40*z40).precision` is `34` as you expected.

Comment: Aha! I get the same result with Scala 2.9.2.  However, the example code in the question was run on 2.10.0-RC1, which must have a bug!  Thanks, your simple observation saved me a lot of time.  I'll have to see if later release candidates fix this bug.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting incorrect behavior in 2.10.0-RC5.  Any ideas on how to track the problem down?

Comment: Sure, `apply(MathContext)` works to get the result back to the right level of precision.  Ideally, I'd rather not clutter my code with expressions like `(1+z40*z40)(z40.mc)`, but maybe I'll have to.

Comment: Please don't add pictures containing text to your posts. Just copy the text directly to make your post search-, edit- and copyable.

Comment: @sschaef Yes, you're right. I removed the picture and replace it with text. Thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe the last line

```
(1 + z40*z40).precision
```

produces the result `34` (not `81`).  I don't think the precision is actually increasing here.

Comment: Agreed.  See my comment on @ntalb's answer about 2.9.2 vs 2.10.0-RC1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create BigDecimals:

```
val z1 = BigDecimal(1, new java.math.MathContext(
  40, java.math.RoundingMode.valueOf(
    scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP.toString)))

val z40 = BigDecimal(0, new java.math.MathContext(
  40, java.math.RoundingMode.valueOf(
    scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP.toString)))
```

Can't see any precision explosion. Just use a proper `MathContext`.

Comment: When I wrote my own BigDecimal form, I played with the Java tool first. The problem with setting MathContext is computations take significantly longer. It appears the code computes all decimals, then truncates them to the desired precision.

Comment: Yep. I've ended up rewriting all operations as a fixed-point math on 2 `long`-s (enough for currency values).

Comment: Speaking of correctness in general - you have no choice, only supply `MathContext` on each step. But maybe you have a different working idea?

Comment: If one will use the Java tool, there is no choice. It is also why I did write my own tool from scratch, but it runs in MATLAB. Anyway, it can be a lot of fun to write efficient code for many of the special functions, trying to get hundreds or many thousands of digits out the end. (Ok, fun is a relative thing.)